# Есть стандартный layout для python проектов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, архитектура, package

Есть стандартный layout для python проектов? Например, для golang [такой](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) сделан.

Меня интересует структура проекта для микросервиса.

Comment: Что такое layout в вашем понимании?

Comment: @Kromster структура проекта

Comment: Структура какого рода проекта?

Comment: Простой ответ: нет никакого стандартного лейаута для всех Python проектов. Более сложный: для Django есть свой лейаут (причем допускающий вольности), есть лейаут для пакетов для последующей заливки на pipy. Для микросервиса (если это действительно **микро**сервис) - возможно будет всего один модуль, какой уж тут лейаут.

Comment: @insolor хорошо, нет. Но в языке, в целом, есть устоявшиеся подходы. Сейчас, как мне кажется этот подход состоит в следующем: "если ты не джанго, то кто -- в лес, кто -- по дрова".

Comment: `Сейчас, как мне кажется этот подход состоит в следующем: "если ты не джанго, то кто -- в лес, кто -- по дрова"` - именно так. Именно этим мне Python подход нравится больше, чем подход golang - "по максимуму ограничить, предписать, запретить". В Python нужно больше думать головой, а не ссылаться на предписания "старших братьев" (хотя и не без этого - вспомним дзен или PEP8, но этого не так уж много).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Питоне разрабатываются проекты для разных задач и под разные платформы с использованием различных фреймворков, движков и прочих технологий. Структуры проектов ничто не ограничивает и мало кто регламентирует, поэтому зачастую они получаются очень специфическими для конкретного проекта.

Среди фреймворков, свою *стандартную* структуру проектов продвигает **Django** (там она формируется автоматически командой `django-admin startproject mysite`). Схематично это выглядит так:

```
[projectname]/
├── [projectname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Подробнее о ней можно узнать [в соответствующем вопросе на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23469321/5308802) и [в этой доке](https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html). Однако стоит заметить, что ничто не мешает создать Django-проект с любой другой структурой.

Также, структуру проекта задаёт **Flask**, но не стандартно и автоматически, а только [небольшим описанием в документации](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/layout/).

Большинство других фреймворков никак не регламентируют структуру проектов (вероятно, в виду не такой популярности, как у того же Django), и разработчики-пользователи_библиотек сами выбирают подходы руководствуясь опытом, спецификой проекта и здравым смыслом. Например, как в [этом обсуждении структуры проектов на **PyGame**](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/279oiw/so_how_do_you_organize_your_pygame_game/).

Answer (score 1):

Как было сказано в ответе @AivanF., существует `layout` для `django`. У меня к нему есть несколько вопросов. Для того, чтобы прояснить для себя эти вопросы и структурировать их, я сделал репозиторий, в котором описал то, как я структурирую мои [проекты](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/python-service-layout). Существуют несколько сущностей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Интеграционные тесты
- Сервис, CLI и другие API
- Core-library
- Unit-тесты
- API-core

## Интеграционные тесты

Тесты общаются только с API посредстам публичных интерфейсов. Именно их они и тестируют.

## Сервис, CLI и другие API

В пакете, который публикуется в pypi-registry содержатся все публичные интервейсы. Их можно использовать как консольные утилиты, например, или как сервера. Они идут в комплекте с установщиком. Ипортировать в других библиотеках их запрещено.

## Core-library

Все функции, которые реализуют бизнес-логику, обращения к другим базам данных и т.д.

## Core-API

Публичные функции, которые доступны для импорта в других пакетах.

Comment: Это не ответ на ваш вопрос. Это скорее реклама своего варианта лейаута.

Comment: @insolor пожалуйста. Можете заминусовать. Я использую SO, в т.ч. как коллекцию решения своих проблем, которые я могу быстрой найти